# How to shorten the touch time to select and move a component? (Using UICollectionViewDragDelegate)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

We're using the `UICollectionViewDragDelegate` to apply drag and drop functionality in an iOS Swift app so that we can move components on the screen. The default time to select a component feels too long. Is it possible to shorten the time in any way?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see this is entirely handled by the device and you can't override it programmatically.

In Settings -> General -> Accessibility -> Touch Accommodations -> Hold Duration

See this question also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/301467/how-to-adjust-tap-and-hold-time-on-ipad-in-ios-11